# writeline problem in python

Tags: python

I have a very basic problem. I am learning my first steps with python & scripting in general and so even this makes me wonder:

I want to read & write lines to new file:

```
ifile=open("C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSS.csv", "r")
ofile = open("C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSSout.csv", "w")

#read first line with headers
line1 = ifile.readline()
print line1

#read following lines which contain data & write it to ofile
for line in ifile:
    if not line:
        break
    ofile.write(line)
```

if i print this to the screen i get all my lines done nicely:

```
0,26100,568,8636
0,11130,555,**3570
0,57100,77,2405**
0,60120,116,1193
0,33540,166,5007
0,95420,318,2310
0,20320,560,7607
0,4300,692,3969
0,65610,341,2073
0,1720,0,0
0,78850,228,1515
0,78870,118,1222
```

If i write it to ofile i end up missing some 15 lines:

```
0,6100,948,8332
0,26100,568,8636
0,11130,555
```

I would appreciate if someone could point out to me what is it that i don´t understand?

Reg,

Jaani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling ofile.close() according to [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

I'm not sure that writes are fully flushed out to a file without an explicit close.

Also, as SilentGhost mentioned, check for empty lines in your input file.

And as mentioned by stefanw below, that "if.. break" statement isn't necessary in a for in.

Comment: Well, this was fast.

Ofile.close really did it for some reason i do not yet know but sure will find out.

Thank you guys!!

Jaani

Comment: if that did it, please mark as the answer. the reason it worked is that it flushed out the write to the file.  writes are usually done in memory and written out when the buffer gets so big, or close is called.

Comment: if `.close` did it, you're probably are not telling us the full story.

Answer (score 4):

```
#read following lines which contain data & write it to ofile
for line in ifile:
    if not line:
        continue          #break stops the loop, you should use continue
    ofile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

The "if not line:" - Check is unnecessary.

```
for line in ifile:
    ofile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using python2.4? the latest is python2.6

and then you can use

```
from contextlib import nested
ipath = "C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSS.csv"
opath = "C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSSout.csv"
with nested(open(ipath,'r'), open(opath,'w') as ifile, ofile:

    #read first line with headers
    line1 = ifile.readline()
    print line1

    #read following lines which contain data & write it to ofile
    for line in ifile:
        ofile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, why does it look so foolish, the formation i mean?
Give it another go...

hi,

I have a very basic problem. I am learning my first steps with python & scripting in general and so even this makes me wonder:

I want to read & write lines to new file:

ifile=open("C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSS.csv", "r") 
ofile = open("C:\Python24\OtsakkeillaSPSSout.csv", "w")

read first line with headers
line1 = ifile.readline() 
print line1
read following lines which contain data & write it to ofile

for line in ifile: 
    if not line: 
        break 
    ofile.write(line)

if i print this to the screen i get all my lines done nicely:

0,26100,568,8636 
0,11130,555,3570 
0,57100,77,2405 
0,60120,116,1193 
0,33540,166,5007 
0,95420,318,2310 
0,20320,560,7607 
0,4300,692,3969 
0,65610,341,2073 
0,1720,0,0 
0,78850,228,1515 
0,78870,118,1222

If i write it to ofile i end up missing some 15 lines:

0,6100,948,8332 
0,26100,568,8636 
0,11130,555

I would appreciate if someone could point out to me what is it that i don´t understand?

Reg,

Jaani

Comment: Please just edit this into your question, instead of making an answer for it.